# Difference between images.google.com and google.com/images?

Tags: html, url, web

This question has probably been asked before, but I wasn't sure what terminology to look up.

What is the difference between [images.google.com](http://images.google.com) and [google.com/images](http://google.com/images)? Not just Google specifically, but any website that uses this? If you visit the links the URLs are different, but the site appears to be the same. So what is the difference?

Comment: both are same. why are you asking such type of question?

Comment: images.google.com is subdomain url but google.com/images is a folder in google domain

Comment: @Gautam Jha just curious

Comment: Why do they use both if they seem to do the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They most likely do this for ease of access. Some users might go to google.com/images and some users might go to images.google.com

They might also have images.google.com to stop fake phishing websites.